# Can the honorific お be used with a person's name?

Tags: honorifics

I have seen the honorific used in front of nouns and was wondering if it can be used in front of a person's name. Thank you.

Comment: I've only seen it used with names in the case of deities, such as お稲荷{いなり}さん

Comment: 昔は女性の名前に「お」をつけましたけどね・・・「お雪」「おトミさん」「お菊さん」「お銀」「おカヨちゃん」とか。。。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can certainly be.  Don't just take my word for it; Look it up in a [dictionary, preferably a monolingual one,](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1-448357#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) yourself.  For instance, デジタル大辞泉 gives the definition:

> ２ 女性{じょせい}の名{な}に付{つ}いて、尊敬{そんけい}、親{した}しみの意{い}を表{あらわ}す。

My translation of that would be:

> "Attached to feminine names, it expresses respect and/or intimacy"

[おしん, the TV drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oshin) became popular around the world so it needs no introduction.  The heroine's name is しん, so that お is the honorific.

Next, let me introduce my neighbor お珠{たま}さん, whose real given name is 珠子{たまこ}.

Finally, here is the well-known song called おゆき.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3f3dEPn8nk

Comment: Hmmm... While true, I'm not convinced by the example of お珠 - it is more akin to a nice nickname (Lady T) rather than adding お to a real name. And in that case it's not strictly feminine, starting with お拾様.

Answer (score 0):

No it can not be used with people's actual names. It's on added to nouns that are used to refer to people. e.g. お相撲{すもう}さん (a sumo wrestler)