# What does 隣村の、おかよが死んだ日にな・・・mean?

Tags: nuances

I was reading children's story and found a part I can not understand. This part is おかよが in the sentense above. Maybe it's simple, but  help, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the honorific お be used with a person's name?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44670/can-the-honorific-%e3%81%8a-be-used-with-a-persons-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the story you are referencing ([百物語の幽霊](http://hukumusume.com/douwa/pc/jap/08/09.htm%20%22%E7%99%BE%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E5%B9%BD%E9%9C%8A)). Judging from the context, かよ is a name of a person who died (お being an honorific). She is from a neighboring village (隣村{となりむら}).

The possessive particle の links 隣村 and おかよ, so that 隣村の、おかよ means "O-Kayo from the neighboring village" (the comma here can be interpreted as a pause in speech). Thus, 隣村の、おかよが死んだ日にな・・・ means "On the day that O-Kayo, from the neighboring village, died..."

Comment: 「かよ」 would be her name and the 「お」 would be the honorific.  Also, since OP says this is a chidren's story, it would not be very natural for 「隣村」 to be read「りんそん」.  It would be read 「となりむら」 99.9% of the time.

Comment: I made the necessary changes. Thank you for the correction.